# $ [x,y]=y, [y,z]=z, [z,x]=x$ implies $x=y=z=e$ in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question about commutators. I'm reading Lang's Algebra, and in the section about free groups, Lang asserts that in a group $G$, if $x,y,z\in G$ satisfies $$ [x,y]=y, [y,z]=z, [z,x]=x$$
where $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is the commutator of $x$ and $y$, then we must have $x=y=z=e$.

How does this hold? From the above relations, we obtain $xy=y^2x, yz=z^2y, zx=x^2z$, but I can't see how to proceed next

Comment: Are you sure it's not $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. The notation can be found in p.69 of the book.

Comment: You wrote "where $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{1}$". This has a typo, right?

Comment: Of course we also get the trivial group if $[x,y]$ is interpreted as $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ and the proof is much easier in that case!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes it is thanks